# jquery.timeago plugin: Won't refresh fuzzy timestamps after new content is loaded

Tags: jquery, livequery, timeago

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js

When I load new content to the Dom, the auto-refresh (of previous content) of the timestamps sstops working (with that new loaded content, works just fine)...

I tried to use a modified version with Livequery on document.ready, but didn't work either..

The function to load new content is:

```
function reload_timeline(filter, more, update) {
    if (update) {
        $("#new_updates").hide();
    }
    beforeTimelineLoad(more, update);
    $.post("/ajax/timeline_box_" + timeline_type + ".php", {
        filter: filter,
        timeline_type: timeline_type,
        timeline_user_id: timeline_user_id,
        smaller_id: timeline_smaller_id,
        bigger_id: timeline_bigger_id,
        start: timeline_start,
        more: more,
        update: update
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0 && timeline_type == "home") $("#pilltabs").show();
        afterTimelineLoad(data, more, update, filter);
    });
}
```

I tried doing something like

```
$("abbr.timeago", data).timeago();
```

in the "afterTimelineLoad" function, to apply the timeago() function to only the new abbr.timeago in the data, but dind't work either...

I really don't know what to try... Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

can you show the code how u use the livequery?

i am using it this way and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("abbr.timeago").livequery(function() {
        $(this).timeago();
    });
});
```